# Kohana_Request_Exception [ 0 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI:

Tags: exception, controller, kohana, uri

i have a kohana site and i want to put it into production, but i have a problem i don't know how to solve best:
if someone accesses a uri that doesn't exist, relatively to my website, an error page appears, with the header message:

> Kohana_Request_Exception [ 0 ]: Unable
>   to find a route to match the URI:  (and the uri here)

i wonder if I can do something to redirect the user to a standard 404 page, when he/she accesses such a URI,can I?

thank you very much!

Comment: Why dont read manuals? http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/tutorials/error-pages

Comment: And please - show your Kohana version (3.0.x/3.1.x). Its important because of Request API changes.

Comment: i've read the content of the page you linked, but it totally confuses me. i need a solution that will work for all my pages, not for every controller separately.

Comment: This tutorial shows you how to catch all exceptions with its custom handler (`Error::exception_handler(Exception $e)`) and _one_ special error controller (`Controller_Error_Handler`)

Comment: check if [redirect](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Request#redirect) works for you dana.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your `$request->execute()` in your `APPPATH/bootstrap.php` with a try/catch block and then do whatever you want.

Mine looks like this...

```
try 
{
    // Attempt to execute the response
    $request->execute();
}
catch (Kohana_Request_Exception $e)
{
    if (Kohana::$environment === Kohana::DEVELOPMENT) throw $e;

    // Log the error
    Kohana::$log->add(Kohana::ERROR, Kohana::exception_text($e));

    // Create a 404 response
    $request->status = 404;
    $request->response = Request::factory('errors/404')->execute();

}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    if (Kohana::$environment === Kohana::DEVELOPMENT) throw $e;

    // Log the error
    Kohana::$log->add(Kohana::ERROR, Kohana::exception_text($e));
    // Create a 500 response
    $request->status = 500;

    $request->response = Request::factory('errors/500')->execute();
}
```

Ideally PHP would support `finally { ... }` and I could do the logging and possible re-throwing there, but what can you do?

Comment: i tryed like that, but it crashes my site. it firstly gives me an error: ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined index: user_id
then i should delete the browser history, and the above lines of code, in order to restore it. i wonder why.

Comment: if i just put the above code in the bootstrap, i get: Undefined variable: request

Comment: You need to assign the instance to it.

Comment: @dana `$request = Request::instance()`.

Comment: i have added it to the end of bootstrap file, but nothing solved. i still get that error if i access a random url relative to my website: Kohana_Request_Exception [ 0 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI instead of going into a custom 404 page

Comment: @dana. Can you show your code (bootstrap.php entry, error controller, maybe exception screenshot) with pastebin.com?

Answer (score 3):

You can handle all errors the same way it is described in the userguide for http exceptions:

http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/errors#http-exception-handling

Answer (score 2):

Try out this one

```
    define('IN_PRODUCTION', TRUE);
 // Instantiate your Request object
    $request = Request::instance();
    try
    {
        $request->execute();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) // if its not valid, it gets caught here
    {
        if (! IN_PRODUCTION) // if this is Development, its displays the error
        {
            throw $e;
        }
        // if its IN_PRODUCTION, it does the following:
        // Logs the error
        Kohana::$log->add(Kohana::ERROR, Kohana::exception_text($e));
        // Marks the status as 404
        $request->status = 404;
         $request->response = $request->factory('sitemap')->execute();
    }
    // then continues on with the request process to display your custom 404 page
    $request->send_headers()->response;
    echo $request->response;
```